# CountDownTimer stops when PopupWindow appears

Tags: android, popupwindow, countdowntimer, android-popupwindow

In an Android activity I'm using a `CountDownTimer` as follows:

```
    timer = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%ds", millisUntilFinished / 1000));

            if (millisUntilFinished <= 10000) {
                // Blinking text
                ViewUtil.setBlinking(timeView,Animation.INFINITE);
            } else {
                timeView.clearAnimation();
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            timeView.clearAnimation();
            timeView.setText("0s");
    }.start();
```

This timer just counts backwards in seconds. In the same activity I also showing a popup window using `PopupWindow` class as follows:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ConstraintLayout mRelativeLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.task_layout);
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window,mRelativeLayout,false);
        mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                customView,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        mPopupWindow.setElevation(5.0f);
        mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(mRelativeLayout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
```

The problem is that as soon as the popup window appears, the `CountDownTimer` stops somehow. What I want is that the `CountDownTimer` runs also when the popup window appears and the background view gets still updated.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `CountDownTimer` in UI thread, when you popup window the thread goes for that window, however I searched through `PopupWindow` documentation but it has weak documentation couldn't found much

Using `CountDownTimer` in a background solve it. Using `Asynctask`, `Service` or `Runnable`

Comment: Thank you so much. But how can I update the UI (the TextView) from the background thread?

Comment: Welcome, preferred approach for UI updates is Asynctask. update UI in onPostExecute

Comment: But I want to update every second (counting a timer down). onPostExecute is only executed once...

Comment: @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if(timer =! null)
            doInBackground();
    }

Comment: up code call doInBackground after updating the UI, but put a Runnable postDelayed 1000ms in onPostExecute because it will be headache for the processor and may through exception

Comment: something like

    (@)Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            (@)Override
            public void run() {
                if(timer =! null)
                    doInBackground();
            }
        },1000);

    }

    make timer null onDestroy